# How to set Vagrant ssh timeout

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile

I'm having a chef cookbook to apply patches to Redhat OS. After registering to RH satellite server, it runs `yum -y update`. The rhel 6.4 image I'm using to test the cookbook has 255 packages to be updated.

But it always failed at around 210th package, with no message error, it only said

```
"return 1" instead of 0.
```

I also increased my vagrant box to 1GB ram, and still failed.
I'm suspecting the vagrant ssh timeout. But I couldnt find anything but this old document:
http://friendsofvagrant.github.io/v1/docs/config/ssh/timeout.html

Anyone knows what is the default ssh timeout that Vagrant set to ssh to the provisioned VM? And how to configure it?

Here is my Vagrantfile (auto-generated by kitchen-vagrant plugin)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |c|
  c.vm.box = "redhat-6.4"
  c.vm.box_url = "https://myrepo.domain.com/vagrant/rhel-6.4-x86_64.box"
  c.vm.hostname = "default-redhat-64.vagrantup.com"
  c.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  c.vm.provider :virtualbox do |p|
    p.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end
end
```

Here is the output:

```
Updating   : systemtap-2.5-5.el6.x86_64                               201/517 
Updating   : gcc-c++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64                              202/517 
Updating   : gcc-gfortran-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64                         203/517 
Updating   : system-config-firewall-tui-1.2.27-7.1.el6.noarch         204/517 
Updating   : sysstat-9.0.4-27.el6.x86_64                              205/517 
Updating   : ntp-4.2.6p5-1.el6.x86_64                                 206/517 
Updating   : 2:irqbalance-1.0.4-10.el6.x86_64                         207/517 
Updating   : selinux-policy-targeted-3.7.19-260.el6.noarch            208/517 
Updating   : lvm2-2.02.111-2.el6.x86_64                               209/517 
Updating   : openss57.641417 #4720]  INFO -- default-redhat-64: 
I, [2015-01-07T13:31:57.642725 #4720]  INFO -- default-redhat-64: h-server-5.3p1-104.el6.x86_64                      210/517
I, [2015-01-07T13:31:57.642775 #4720]  INFO -- default-redhat-64: STDERR: 
I, [2015-01-07T13:31:57.642830 #4720]  INFO -- default-redhat-64: ---- End output of yum -y update ----
I, [2015-01-07T13:31:57.642884 #4720]  INFO -- default-redhat-64: Ran yum -y update returned 1
I, [2015-01-07T13:31:59.151150 #4720]  INFO -- default-redhat-64: [2015-01-07T20:31:58+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253495 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: Converge failed on instance <default-redhat-64>.
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253739 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: ------Exception-------
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253782 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253813 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sudo -E chef-client -z --config /tmp/kitchen/client.rb --log_level info --json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json]
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253846 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: ---Nested Exception---
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253874 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: Class: Kitchen::SSHFailed
E, [2015-01-07T13:32:00.253906 #4720] ERROR -- default-redhat-64: Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sudo -E chef-client -z --config /tmp/kitchen/client.rb --log_level info --json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json]
```

Again, it doesnt always fail at one specific package.

Comment: can you paste the real error log around `210th package`. I don't think it related with memory usage.

Comment: Please include the full output around the error.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out there is no timeout in Vagrant ssh (likely in later Vagrant versions). The issue was in Mixlib ShellOut that has a timeout of 600s, and the command "yum update" took longer than that.